# iOS, AppStore, Default-568h@2x.png and 4" view mode deactivation

Tags: ios, iphone, ios6, ios7, app-store

I have tried to submit my App via AppLoader and it requires "Default-568h@2x.png" file. This in turns enables the 4" view. As I developed my game for a 3.5" view (is a vertical scrolling shooter game) I am wondering how I can include the required "Default-568h@2x.png" and disable the 4" view mode.

Answer (score 2):

You don't. Newly submitted apps must support 4" devices.